# Multiple instance of Sharedpreference gives different value for same field

Tags: android

I am trying to read the value of a field in sharedpreference using two different instances of sharepreferences. While read by using the first instance is giving the correct result, the second read operation using second instance is returning the default values.Why is it so?Am I missing some important concept here?

Code:

```
  public void testMethod(){

    SharedPreferences pref1=myContext.getSharedPreferences(PreferenceHelper.MY_PREF, myContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Correct value is obtained here...
    String value1=pref1.getString("KEY", "");

    SharedPreferences pref2=myContext.getSharedPreferences(PreferenceHelper.MY_PREF, myContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Incorrect value is obtained here...
    String value2=pref2.getString("KEY", "");

}
```

I am doubting this is due to multiple instances of the same preference.Android documentation states:

```
 Only one instance of the SharedPreferences object is returned to any callers for the same name, meaning they will see each other's edits as soon as they are made.
```

Does my case relates to concept in this sentence?

Comment: What's being returned by each instance? When/where are you setting the values?

Comment: The value from first read is actual value I had set.The second read returning the default value "".I had set values for fields in another class.

Comment: Did you forget to call pref2.apply() perhaps when you were saving the values?

Comment: did you mean commit() call on preference editor?I did call.That is why  I am getting expected result on first read.

Comment: Put my response as an answer so you can accept :)

Answer (score 5):

Since your invoking commit() and not apply(), one of them isn't saving and you're getting the wrong answer. Check out the docs:

Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are completed as well as the commit itself.

The above from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: @Hungry Androider, you have shown some new concepts.Thats quite useful.But I am not doing any commit operation between two read operations in my codes. So, shouldnt it have given me same results?

Comment: It might be that the commit() didn't take place yet when you called the second getString(). Did you try with apply() ?

Comment: @Hungry Androider, I have noticed that when I use a instance variable of sharedpreference and read preference fields using that, it is always giving me correct result.dont know why!!

Comment: @Hungry Androider, if commit didnt take place when i am reading second time, it means didnt take place in reading first time too.So, even the first result would have been wrong.I have discovered some interesting things that I have mentioned in earlier comment..

Comment: That's a good point about reading the first and second time. You're not clearing this value anywhere either?